# Is Bob gender neutral?

Tags: names, gender

Recently [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390444/5407188) on Stack Overflow meta was edited by a moderator to remove the name Nancy with a gender neutral name Bob. His exact words were(emphasis mine)

> Jon suggested Bob would work too. I like Bob. I have two uncles named
>   Bob. ***Good gender-neutral name, Uncle Bob***

Now to my actual question, I have so far heard the name Bob or Uncle Bob to denote male gender. I have never heard it used as a gender neutral name until now. Is the name Bob gender neutral?

Comment: ***Note: Comment not answer due to anecdotal-only status!*** I do not see it as such, although _in speech, not writing_, "Bobby/Bobbi" might be considered gender-neutral. Also in _speech, not writing_, "Joe/Jo" might serve as a gender-neutral name. The two names that I most often see as gender-neutral are "Chris" (for Christopher/Christine) and "Leslie" (unusual alternate spelling "Lesley"); I've also occasionally encountered "Audr(e)y" used by both men and women.

Comment: That statement confused me too as a native speaker. I know those of use participating in Meta are a little bit exhausted by the conversation there, but I don't think this question deserves to be closed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The names chosen in those computing examples are generally not for gender-related informational purposes, but simply because they start with **A** and **B** respectively. If a third person is involved in the sequence, the name chosen may be male or female, but will start with **C**, and a fourth party will start with **D**. Please don't confuse the issue with irrelevant information.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why do you believe it is it off-topic to ask why someone said “Bob” was neutral gender? There's things like “Bob’s your uncle”, the A/B convention and other odd idioms and such that aren’t found in dictionaries. It could have been a joke that didn’t translate.

Comment: @ColleenV: I haven't got involved in the recent "gender wars" here on SO (but I assume *you* have, and you can take it for granted I agree with anything you've got to say on the matter unless it conflicts with Monica Cellio's position! :). But Google is getting pretty good at "natural language processing", so I just searched for ***is bob a girls name or a boys name***...

Comment: @FumbleFingers Stuff here is not off-topic simply because it can be Googled and/or has an obvious-to-a-native-speaker answer. The OP thought Bob was a male name, but someone who appears to be fluent seems to be saying otherwise. I really think this is clearly on-topic, but folks are free to disagree with me.

Comment: @ColleenV: I will admit that my closevote may have been influenced by the ongoing "gender shitstorm" (which I feel is getting *particularly* troubling for me now it's actually hit SO big time). Perhaps in another universe I might have simply downvoted the question rather than closevoting. But (rather curiously, on reflection) I find I have more compunctions about casting a ***down*** vote than a ***close*** vote. I won't keep banging on though. I have my own opinions on this issue, but I don't feel any great urge to hector others into falling in line with my position. Live and let live, I say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did Google the question before asking it here. All the results in the first two pages were about a UK phrase "bob is your uncle" and a phrase about Bob related to photography. Google results are not same in every region.

Comment: Names do not have genders. Only people do. It's up to each person to tell you what gender they identify with. Also, no English word has a gender. They might have associations, but there aren't any that are *grammatically* gendered in the same way that some words in some other languages are. So, *every* word and *every* name might be considered gender neutral. If you make the assumption that somebody called Bob identifies as male, you could be making a mistake. I believe that Jordan was commonly considered a male name—until it wasn't. (And Bob could also be a last name.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No,** Bob is not a gender-neutral name. It is overwhelmingly a male name.

"Bobby" is slightly closer to neutral, as it can be a shortened form of (among other possibilities) "Robert" (male) or "Roberta" (female). In the modern generation though this is still much more commonly a male name.

[Gender-API.com](https://gender-api.com/), with which I am in no way affiliated, provides a gender inference service based on source data they describe as follows:

> To provide the highest possible accuracy, we combine the data of multiple data sources. We use data from publicly available governmental sources and combine them with data we crawl from social networks, which provides you the best possible matches. Each name has to be verified by different sources to be added to our list.

The results for the name "Bob" are:

- Gender: **male**
- **Accuracy: 99%**
- Samples: 12966

I can't vouch for the scientific quality of their data, but I do empirically agree completely with the result. To my knowledge I have never met a "Bob" or "Bobby" who identified female (but I have met both male and female "Bobbie").

Comment: To add to that, we have a phrase in the UK "Hey presto! Bob's your uncle, Fanny's your aunt" meant to represent the most obvious two facts in the world